# How to implements a button tag to form_for helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, helper

I need implements a helper that creates `<button>...</button>` tag, I need to do some similar to this:

```
<%= form_for(some_var) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit '+' %>
<% end %>
```

The helper should work like this:

```
<%= f.button '+' %>
# Returns
<button type="submit">+</button>
```

I saw https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L458 but this isn't implemented in Rails 3.0.7.

What I need to do to implements this helper in my application?

Comment: I think that use the helper is smarter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a custom form helper that inherits from FormBuilder to use when creating forms. I created this button method to use with Twitter's Bootstrap.

Replace 'Bootstrap' with whatever fits. (Perhaps CuteAsAButtonBuilder?)

*`app/helpers/bootstrap_form_builder.rb`*

```
class BootstrapFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
    def button(label, options={})

    # You can also set default options, like a class
    default_class = options[:class] || 'btn'
    @template.button_tag(label.to_s.humanize, :class => default_class)    
  end

end
```

Now you have two ways to use the builder.

#### 1. DRY for ducks

Every time you build a form that uses the button, you need to specify the builder...

```
<%= form_for @duck, :builder => BootstrapFormBuilder do |form|%>
```

#### 2. DRY for devs

Add the following

*`app/helpers/application_helper.rb`*

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def bootstrap_form_for(name, *args, &block)
    options = args.extract_options!
    form_for(name, *(args << options.merge(:builder => BootstrapFormBuilder)), &block)
  end
end
```

Just call the magic builder...

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @person do |form| %>
  <%= form.button 'Click Me' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just had the exact same use case! Much useful :)

Comment: A tiny bug fix: the button method definition should be def button(label, options={}), otherwise options[:class] is always nil

Comment: Too true. Just fixed it. I had accidentally forgotten `options=args.extract_options!` which does the trick just as well, but the hash looks oh so pretty.

Answer (score 2):

I had implemented a similar helper method in one of my applications earlier. I needed the button tag with an image on the button and a class of its own. You can pass either a string which is the text that is displayed on the button or the object itself. It looks like this:

```
def submit_button(object)
    image   = "#{image_tag('/images/icons/tick.png', :alt => '')}"

    if object.is_a?(String)
      value = "#{image}#{object}"
    else
      name  = object.class.to_s.titlecase
      value = object.new_record? ? "#{image} Save #{name} Information" : "#{image} Update #{name} Information"
    end

    content_tag :button, :type => :submit, :class => 'button positive' do
      content_tag(:image, '/images/icons/tick.png', :alt => '')
      value
    end
  end
```

Then you call this in the form `<%= submit_button @admission %>`

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: your solution works but I want implements like `f.button` to looks like other inputs. I can copy the Rails 3.1 button_tag in helpers and use this but I think that use `f.button` contributes to make the code more legible.

Comment: @jrdi Yes, you can always override the default implementation. Provided you remember that you've overridden and make sure it doesn't break anything else and communicate that to the team. Or, take this route and implement a different method altogether and use that instead. No hassles.